# Converting List<CustomObject> to JSON

Tags: c#, json

I have a list of type Facility, class below.

I want to take that list which contains objects with parameters and serialize that data into json.

The problem with my current implementation is I get back a list that looks like: `[],[],[],[],[]` ....but my object **has** the data in it  that I can access like so: `_facility[0].FacilityName` OR `_facility[0].FacilityId`.  But when I serialize this I am not getting those values.

How do I drill down to get this data and serialize it?

Facility.cs

```
public class Facility : List<Facility>
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Facility")]
    public string FacilityName { get; set; }
    public string FacilityIdSource { get; set; }

    public Facility()
    {
        // Default Constructor
    }

    public Facility(string facilityName, string facilityIdSource)
    {
        this.FacilityName = facilityName;
        this.FacilityIdSource = facilityIdSource;
    }
}
```

Code that is called to populate the Facility class

```
 public async Task<string> FacilitiesAsync()
    {
        ViewBag.SyncOrAsync = "Asynchronous";
        var service = new FacilitiesService();

        this._facilities = new List<Facility>();

        _facilities = await service.GetFacilitiesBySourceDbAsync("param");

        string json = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < _facilities.Count; i++)
        {
            json += JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_facilities[i].FacilityName);
        }

        return json;
    }
```

Now I see the json in my alert box from the complete function in my jQuery.  How do I assign this the the array for availableTags?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    var result = null;
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function () {
            alert("Testing");
        },
        url: "FacilitiesAsync",
        success: function (data) {
            result = data;
        },
        complete: function () {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
});

$(function () {
    var availableTags = [
        // Place results from JSON here
    ];
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
</script>
```

Comment: As a debugging step, try to use `JavaScriptSerializer`. Do you get the intended result?

Comment: `Facility : List<Facility>`? That makes my brain hurt. :(

Comment: (but seriously, I don't see how you'd sensibly serialize a class like that into JSON; you could probably have a `Facility` class with a `List<Facility> Children` property)

Comment: It seems like based on his code a Facility can not have child facilities.  It seems like a Facility just has a name and an id.  You should remove the `: List<Facility>` part.

Answer (score 0):

The default serializer will not serialize properties on objects that implement ICollection.

From the article introducing XML Serialization:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh(v=vs.110).aspx

**Items That Can Be Serialized**

The following items can be serialized using the XmLSerializer class:

- Public read/write properties and fields of public classes.
- Classes that implement ICollection or IEnumerable.

**Note: Only collections are serialized, not public properties.**

- XmlElement objects.
- XmlNode objects.
- DataSet objects.

The DataContractSerializer should handle this correctly.

Comment: For serialization it makes it simpler if you include the collection as a readonly property, as long as that fits your interface requirements I would try that.